# How do I make the background stretch the browser height?

Tags: html, css

Essentially, I'm looking for a full browser height landing page. However it seems that the background is applied only for the height of the content. I styled the parent container to have 100% browser height.

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  background: #202020;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#header .content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}
#header p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
#header .name {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-spacing: 12px;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
#header .tagline {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding-top: 30px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
#header .icons {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#header .icons i {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
#header .icons a {
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.3;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#header .icons a:hover {
  opacity: 4;
}
#header .scroll {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline;
  bottom: 36px;
  opacity: .3;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
#header .scroll:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <div class="content">
    <p class="name">Text Name</p>
    <p class="tagline">Some blurb goes here</p>
    <div class="icons">
      <a href="http://www.github.com/">
        <i class="fa fa-github-alt fa-lg"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.twitter.com/">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="mailto:test">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-lg"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="scroll" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-lg"></i>
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: _“I styled the parent container to have 100% browser height”_ – no, you did not (at least not with the code you have shown us – a height in percent requires an explicit height to be set for the parent element as well.)

Comment: `html, body {min-height:100%,}` ??

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the `#header` you could put the background to the `body`:

```
body {
  background: #202020;  
}
```

Or you can set the `height` of the parent, which i guess is `body`:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;  
}
```

Note that you should also set the height of the `html` because `body` is child of `html`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height of elements in relation to the viewport.  There's a reference for this on [Web Design Weekly](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/).

The units for this (taken from the site) are:

- vw: 1/100th viewport width
- vh: 1/100th viewport height
- vmin: 1/100th of the smallest side
- vmax: 1/100th of the largest side

If you set the main container to 100vh, it will be the height of the viewport.  It's good for getting full height images, but needs to be used with caution as (in my experience) things can get a bit odd when content is too long for the window height, and scrolling is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the body which contains your content 100% height. 
Try:

```
html,body{
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also,

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Backstretch, a simple jQuery plugin that allows you to add a dynamically-resized, slideshow-capable background image to any page or element.